# Test promise with delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to test a method that accept as argument a promise, but this promise is never resolved!
The code:

```
function blockQueueUntilResolved (aPromise) {
  aPromise.finally(releaseBlock)
  queueBlocked = true
}

function releaseBlock () {
  // other things..
}
```

The test:

```
describe('given ...', function () {
  var initDefer
  var initPromise
  var fn1
  var fn2
  var promise1Resolved = false
  var promise2Resolved = false

  it('queueBlocked is set to true', function () {
    // initDefer = $q(function (resolve) {
    //   initPromise = resolve
    // })
    initDefer = $q.defer()
    // initPromise = initDefer.promise

    fn1 = function () {
      console.log('fn1 called')
      promise1Resolved = true
    }

    fn2 = function () {
      console.log('fn2 called')
      promise2Resolved = true
    }

    QueueService.blockQueueUntilResolved(initDefer.promise)
    QueueService.push(fn1)
    QueueService.push(fn2)

    expect(QueueService.isBlocked()).to.be.true
  })

  it('promises in the queue are not processed', function () {
    expect(promise1Resolved).to.be.false
    expect(promise2Resolved).to.be.false
  })

  describe('when the blocked promise is resolved', function () {
    it('resolve', function () {
      // initPromise()
      initDefer.resolve()
    })

    it('promises in the queue are processed', function () {
      expect(promise1Resolved).to.be.true
      expect(promise2Resolved).to.be.true
    })
  })
})
```

I tried both strategy to promise, with defer and with this constructor, but none works.
`promise1Resolved` and `promise2Resolved` are always false and the related logs are not called.
What's wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was in angular itself. The `$q` service depends on the `$digest` service, so the promise are not resolved until the digest is called.

The fix is:

```
describe('given ...', function () {
  var initDefer
  var fn1
  var fn2
  var promise1Resolved = false
  var promise2Resolved = false

  it('queueBlocked is set to true', function () {
    initDefer = $q.defer()

    fn1 = function () {
      console.log('fn1 called')
      promise1Resolved = true
    }

    fn2 = function () {
      console.log('fn2 called')
      promise2Resolved = true
    }

    QueueService.blockQueueUntilResolved(initDefer.promise)
    QueueService.push(fn1)
    QueueService.push(fn2)

    expect(QueueService.isBlocked()).to.be.true
    // make some assertions
    expect(promise1Resolved).to.be.false
    expect(promise2Resolved).to.be.false

    initDefer.resolve()
    // call the $digest
    $rootScope.$digest()
    // now the promise is resolved

    expect(promise1Resolved).to.be.true
    expect(promise2Resolved).to.be.true
  })
})
```

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10340)